# NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, android, json, исключения

Помогите, что это за ошибка ? В android studio все запускается исправно, но после сборки и запуска, apk выдает это. Есть подозрения на использование JSON, но почему тогда в студии проект работает ?

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ALIVE
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.n$a.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.n$24.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.o(Unknown Source)
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.m(Unknown Source)
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.k(Unknown Source)
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.g(Unknown Source)
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity$a.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4401)
                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18184)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ALIVE
                                                 at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:673)
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.n$a.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.n$24.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.b.a.i.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at com.google.a.e.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.c.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.o(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.m(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.k(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity.g(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity$a.onClick(Unknown Source) 
                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4401) 
                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18184) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

Comment: Код добавьте пожалуйста где валится!

Comment: @Victor в этом и проблема, не указывает точку, все что добавил это все логи

Comment: Покажите код класса SettingsActivity так как game.com.doncov.pasha.mafianarrator.settings.SettingsActivity$a.onClick(Unknown Source)

Comment: + выключите обфускацию на время дебага